# How to upload brushes to Gimp

Tags: gimp

I am trying to upload some new brushes to Gimp and I can't because it is owned by the root.  I have had a quick look at how to do it through sudo BUT as I am VERY new to Ubuntu is it possible to just give me the command so I can just copy it across?

```
user/share/gimp/2.0/brushes
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gimp (here on Gimp 2.8) lets you define the location of brushes in the *Edit  > Preferences* menu:

[image]

By default it is a (hidden) folder in your HOME directory but you can choose any other location. All files and folders in your HOME are accessible withhout sudo permission.

Hidden directories can be viewed in the file manager by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or by ticking "show hidden files" in preferences.

Comment: ...and can be viewed with 'Ctrl'+'H' in Nautilus file manager. *(Note on last bit)*

Comment: And that is why I couldn't find the flippin file it was hidden I thought I was going nuts!  Thank you! :D

Answer (score 4):

Put them in your user's `~/.gimp-2.8/brushes/` folder.

Comment: thank you! it was the fact they were hidden...doh!  now found out how to see them... :D

Answer (score 1):

To install for a single user, copy the file to ~/.gimp-2.x/brushes. 2.x is your version of gimp

For all users, copy it to /usr/share/gimp/2.0/brushes , use sudo

```
 sudo cp your_brush /usr/share/gime/2.0/brushes
```

Comment: thank you! it was the fact they were hidden...doh!  now found out how to see them... :D